# problemas con fechas mysql y php

Tags: php, mysql, datepicker

Saludos estoy intentando hacer una aplicación para el control de personal 
mas que nada para poder guardar en que fecha entro y en que fecha termina su contrato y guardar su fecha de nacimiento he encontrado mucha información sobre el datepicker.

Sonará tonto pero prefiero preguntar que quedarme con la duda. **¿Cómo podria yo poner un date picker en un formulario donde el usuario pueda elegir las fechas que desee. y como se recibirian esos datos en el formato de insercion de datos de php?.**

Aquí les muestro el codigo de como ando capturando estos datos lo que no recuerdo es si al pasar la info al siguiente modulo hay que cambiarle el formato o puedo guardar directamente

```html
<label for="fechalta">Fecha de Alta</label>
<input type="date" name="fechainicio" step="1" min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31" value="<?php echo fechalta;?>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las fechas son sin duda todo un tema jaja aquí te dejo algunas consideraciones:

Antes que nada, revisa el formato en que el DatePicker te devuelva la fecha seleccionada, ya que la base de datos debe tener la misma intención ya sea DateTime (Si incluye hora) o Date (Si solo es la fecha)

De ahí, la mejor manera que he encontrado para no hacerse problemas al meter la fecha a la base de datos es utilizar la siguiente función de MYSQL directamente en el Query:

```
STR_TO_DATE(string, format_mask)
```

Documentación: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp

Con ella puedes hacer uso de la fecha tal cual te la devuelva el datepicker y MYSQL se encargará de crear el string que MYSQL necesita para guardarlo correctamente. El más usado sin duda es:

```
STR_TO_DATE('$fecha_nacimiento', '%d-%m-%Y'),
```

Si tienes alguna duda la documentación muestra las demás 'Format Mask' que puedes usar según necesites.

Espero te sirva de guía para afrontar a las temibles variables de tipo fecha, que de cuando en cuando nos causan pesadillas.